# org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class

Tags: hibernate

i am getting the following Exception while inserting into table Which has two dependencies

look at my Entity classes these are auto generated

**AssocTransportVehicleDriver**

```
package com.rasvek.cg.entity;
// Generated May 14, 2018 11:39:07 PM by Hibernate Tools 5.1.7.Final

import javax.persistence.AttributeOverride;
import javax.persistence.AttributeOverrides;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * AssocTransportVehicleDriver generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "assoc_transport_vehicle_driver", catalog = "campus_guru_01")
public class AssocTransportVehicleDriver implements java.io.Serializable {

    private AssocTransportVehicleDriverId id;
    private TransportDriverInfo transportDriverInfo;
    private TransportVehicleInfo transportVehicleInfo;

    public AssocTransportVehicleDriver() {
    }

    public AssocTransportVehicleDriver(AssocTransportVehicleDriverId id, TransportDriverInfo transportDriverInfo,
            TransportVehicleInfo transportVehicleInfo) {
        this.id = id;
        this.transportDriverInfo = transportDriverInfo;
        this.transportVehicleInfo = transportVehicleInfo;
    }

    @EmbeddedId

    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "vehicleId", column = @Column(name = "vehicle_id", nullable = false)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "tdiId", column = @Column(name = "tdi_id", nullable = false)) })
    public AssocTransportVehicleDriverId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(AssocTransportVehicleDriverId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tdi_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public TransportDriverInfo getTransportDriverInfo() {
        return this.transportDriverInfo;
    }

    public void setTransportDriverInfo(TransportDriverInfo transportDriverInfo) {
        this.transportDriverInfo = transportDriverInfo;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public TransportVehicleInfo getTransportVehicleInfo() {
        return this.transportVehicleInfo;
    }

    public void setTransportVehicleInfo(TransportVehicleInfo transportVehicleInfo) {
        this.transportVehicleInfo = transportVehicleInfo;  
    }

}
```

another `(@Embeddable)` class generated along with this class called

**AssocTransportVehicleDriverId** //what is the use of it

```
@Embeddable
public class AssocTransportVehicleDriverId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int vehicleId;
    private int tdiId;

    public AssocTransportVehicleDriverId() {
    }

    public AssocTransportVehicleDriverId(int vehicleId, int tdiId) {
        this.vehicleId = vehicleId;
        this.tdiId = tdiId;
    }

    @Column(name = "vehicle_id", nullable = false)
    public int getVehicleId() {
        return this.vehicleId;
    }

    public void setVehicleId(int vehicleId) {
        this.vehicleId = vehicleId;
    }

    @Column(name = "tdi_id", nullable = false)
    public int getTdiId() {
        return this.tdiId;
    }

    public void setTdiId(int tdiId) {
        this.tdiId = tdiId;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if ((this == other))
            return true;
        if ((other == null))
            return false;
        if (!(other instanceof AssocTransportVehicleDriverId))
            return false;
        AssocTransportVehicleDriverId castOther = (AssocTransportVehicleDriverId) other;

        return (this.getVehicleId() == castOther.getVehicleId()) && (this.getTdiId() == castOther.getTdiId());
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;

        result = 37 * result + this.getVehicleId();
        result = 37 * result + this.getTdiId();
        return result;
    }

}
```

when i try to insert into `AssocTransportVehicleDriver` the above Exception is occurring .do not know why ?

**AssocTransportVehicleDriver table does not have any Id column in table but it as generated** .

please look at my query

```
                  AssocTransportVehicleDriver obj=null;




                    if(transportVehicleInfoId != 0 && transportDriverInfoId != 0)
                    {
                        TransportVehicleInfo    transportVehicleInfo1 = new TransportVehicleInfo();

                        TransportDriverInfo transportDriverInfo1 = new TransportDriverInfo();

                        transportDriverInfo1.setTdiId(transportDriverInfoId);
                        transportVehicleInfo1.setVehicleId(transportDriverInfoId);


                        obj= new AssocTransportVehicleDriver();

                        obj.setTransportDriverInfo(transportDriverInfo1);
                        obj.setTransportVehicleInfo(transportVehicleInfo1);
                        res=service.addAssocDriverVehicle(obj);
                    }  



@Override
    public boolean addAssocDriverVehicle(AssocTransportVehicleDriver  assocTransportVehicleDriver) {
         boolean success = false;
         try {

                currentSession=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
                currentSession.save(assocTransportVehicleDriver);     
                success=true;  
         }       
         catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }

        return success; 
    }
```

please let me know why its happening. how to insert into  `AssocTransportVehicleDriver` ?

i am very new to hibernate , forgive me if its silly one.

thank you !.

Comment: You didn't set anywhere the id of AssocTransportVehicleDriver

Comment: there is no such column table hibernate generated it, it has generated a Embedable  class class `AssocTransportVehicleDriverId` and kept its reference in `AssocTransportVehicleDriver` automatically.

Comment: AssocTransportVehicleDriver holding two only two foreign keys that's it  `id` has been generated automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EmbeddedId is to tell hibernate that the table has a composite pk `vehicleId/tdiId` in this case.

You have to set it for every instance of `AssocTransportVehicleDriver`
 much like the other fields

```
obj= new AssocTransportVehicleDriver();
obj.setTransportDriverInfo(transportDriverInfo1);
obj.setTransportVehicleInfo(transportVehicleInfo1);
```

How could hibernate generate the insert statement without the Id?

It should be something like this:

```
obj.setId(new AssocTransportVehicleDriverId(vehicleId,tdiId));
```

Comment: thank you @Zeromus you saved my time . can you please tell will it create any issue while retrieving from    AssocTransportVehicleDriver table . i am facing same issue please look at this  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50597110/infinite-loop-while-fetching-data-using-hibernate]